# Converting String to Integer in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, variables

How can you convert string to integer?

I use **Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition**

Comment: Did you try to search using your title? Let's try it. Here a sample http://www.bing.com/search?q=Converting%20String%20to%20Integer%20in%20Visual%20Basic&qs=n&sk=&form=BDKTKB&pc=BDT1&shash=&BDParam=0000&mkt=en-US

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this code:

> **Convert.ToInt32()**

Answer (score 0):

like this, i guess..

```
Convert.toInt32(txt_string.text)
```